# Azure CDN IP Restriction Not working as expected

Tags: azure, ip, cdn, restriction

In my team, we have Azure CDN created with Microsoft tier. An end point is also created for this CDN with (blob)storage as origin. The access level on storage is set to private. Now this works fine but I want to restrict the access to CDN using IP restriction feature as I want this CDN to be accessible only to a certain public IPs. For this I created rule like below:

[Link to rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXkyE.png)
I tried adding a rule to match IPs and to redirect. It did not work. So, I added the negate option to redirect if the ip does not match. Both seem not to work. The result is it redirects for some users and it does not for other users.

Comment: same problem here. NOT IP Match and IP Match are both resulting in the same redirection to the IP that is entered.